# How do I prevent text in Catalyst proposals and insights from losing formatting?

Tags: catalyst

Whenever I edit text in Catalyst proposals and Insights, new-lines are dropped, text that follows bullet points gets indented and previously established formatting is disturbed.

Is there a way to prevent this?  e.g. use a specific browser.

Comment: Within the past week, supposedly improvements to the editor have been made. I hope that these issues will be a thing of the past with this update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now, you cannot, as IdeaScale does not support it. It's embarrassing.

Over time, the Catalyst project hopefully migrates away from IdeaScale to a custom solution. It would be also very cool, if this is built from the catalyst funds by the community.